# Bitmap loses its quality after rotating canvas

Tags: android, canvas, view, bitmap, draw

I have a lot of draw operations in my custom view(compass). I decided to optimize it by drawing whole compass on a bitmap in `onSizeChanged()` method, instead of just drawing it directly every time `onDraw()` triggers.

Here is a part of `onDraw()` method:

```
canvas.rotate(-heading, x, y);
canvas.drawBitmap(compassBitmap, 0f, compassBitmapY, compassBitmapPaint);
```

My problem is what happens after rotation. Bitmap loses its quality. 
Setting `ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG` does not help at all. Is there any way to deal with this problem or should i get back to the "heavier" implementation?

Answer (score 0):

it's impossible to rotate image without loosing it's quality, it's limited by resolution.

Each pixel position need to be recalculed, if new destination is not (int, int) pixels needs to be mixed to be closest from the original image.

[image]
[image]

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/rotate.htm